# Is it feasible to use non-ASCII characters in .gitconfig keys?

Tags: git, config, alias, non-ascii-characters

I'd like to use non-ASCII characters as key strings in my .gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    śtatus = status
```

With such setting, I'm getting “bad config line ...” error in Git Bash (Windows).

Can I escape the characters or do something else to achieve this?

Can the problem be generalised to having non-ASCII characters in Bash variables?

Answer (score 2):

From [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax) syntax:

> Only alphanumeric characters, `-` and `.` are allowed in section names.
>
> The variable names … allow only alphanumeric characters and `-`, and must start with an alphabetic character.

I'm not completely sure what *alphanumeric characters* are but I suspect it's ASCII-only.